# Tensorflow for Deeplearning and Machine learrning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow

We can use TensorFlow for both machine learning and deep learning. So why do we use scikit-learn more in machine learning and not TensorFlow?

Are they both alternatives of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tensorflow` is usually used for deep learning (neural networks) and `scikit` is used for machine learning tasks. You can solve ML problems using `Tensorflow`, of course. But it is much easier to use `scikit` as all you need here is a ready to use algorithm.